# Custom field with 'point' data type for storage

Tags: 8, entities

I created a new entity and added a few base fields using baseFieldDefinitions(). Everything works fine so far. 
The problem is that I would like on this entity to have a field with special storage ( outside of what baseFieldDefinitions() seems to be able to handle ). I want this new field to use the 'point' spatial data type.

Is this possible? If so, it is done via the Typed Data API?

I know that this is vague but I'm trying to get a grasp on these concepts and any pointers will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Not enough detail to say for sure, but it's possible you can create a new field type, which lets you someone set the storage details, that you could then set as the type for your BaseFieldDefinition. Though you'd have to swap out the back-end storage if you wanted to change that futher.

Comment: It should be possible... you can certainly create your own FieldType. Check the docs on `mysql_type` or your database you are using for supported record types. https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Database%21database.api.php/group/schemaapi/8.2.x - note that you might have to do special handling for say, Views fields and filters, as well as provide a FieldFormatter and FieldWidget to display and capture form data.